# Explain the different time scales in Train Fever

Tags: train-fever

I am quite at a loss how to interpret the different times and speeds given in Train Fever.

For example, I have a truck line with horse carts traveling at 15km/h (according to their info). There are two trucks on the line, the frequency is given at "5 minutes", but it takes the truck a few game months to actually go from start to end.

There seem to be three different time scales involved (The truck line does not seem long enough to warrant a few months travel time at 15 km/h).

How do they relate to each other?

Answer (score 1):

I played now until 1910 and think:  **It is badly programmed.**

There is no relating between the Way the Carts travel and the frequency Time. ATM i think the frequency time is only set by the distance of the line and the Carts on the line. 
I had one particular line where all the Carts were in a congo line, so they were not spread over the line but still the frequency time remained the same. So there is no link between the visual appearance of the carts and the game mechanic that set´s the time.

Could be totally wrong but this is what i noticed.

Also the 3 Different speeds change the behavior - if i load a Game and set it in 2 instances on different speed levels my full packed train cost me about 30k more on the slow speed than on high speed.